# How to steal a HTTP packet, change and re-send

Tags: man-in-the-middle, iot, ettercap

I'm doing a project to my college and I have this scenario:

- Arduino (192.168.0.113): Receiving packets and send response
- My router (192.168.0.2): WPS from my gateway
- My gateway (192.168.0.1): Receive the internet and has DHCP Server
- My Attacker (192.168.0.110): Kali Linux
- My Victim (192.168.0.112): Windows 10

I have to send a packet from Victim to Arduino to blink a LED (that's OK). My Attacker make a MITM in the network (arpspoof/ettercap) and that works (I tested with a telnet connection with dsniff and shows in the screen). But I need to steals the packet directed to Arduino, to simulate problems with IoT (stole packets and change of information in clear text).
I try to make a filter in ettercap, but it doesn't work.

**Edited:** I have to send a packet from Victim to the Arduino with information to blink a LED, but I want to steale this packet and change it to make the LED always on, for example.

So I've made a MITM and try to get that specific packet in my network, but I can't find the packet. The packet is sent by a browser from Victim to the Arduino and has a GET variable in URL that inform Arduino what it should do.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your last paragraph, can you edit it? What do want to do exactly?

Comment: You need to get a packet capture, check out wireshark. I can't teach you all there is to know about wireshark but it's an excellent tool.

Comment: I have used wireshark and cannot see any HTTP packet.
I see the TELNET packets and can extract the information. but the HTTP doesn't appear.
I set the MITM between Victim and Gateway (connected via cable)

Comment: HTTP is over TCP and isn't decoded automatically. Select the TCP conversation you suspect is it, go to analyze, and click "follow tcp stream". You should get a pop up with the HTTP data.

Comment: I like to thank you @Sirens.
I simplified the scenario, so I'm able to find the packet that I want.
And I find with HTTP protocol.